# SonataAdminBundle & Password Encoding

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I am using Symfony2.1.x and SonataAdminBundle w/ FOSUserBundle.

I have a new entity that includes a password field. When adding a new entry via admin panel, how do I encode the password?

Also, on another entity form, how do I go about not updating a field to doctrine if it's empty?

Comment: Please keep to only 1 question per post

Answer (score 0):

Is the passwordType isn't what you want ? 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/password.html